# Window fails to enter full screen mode

Tags: osx-lion, fullscreen

`NSWindow` fails to enter full screen with the following error:

> Assertion failure in -[_NSWindowFullScreenTransition
>   makeAndSetupOverlayWindow],
>   /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.47/AppKit.subproj/NSWindowFullScreenTransition.m:696
>   2012-10-26 14:42:49.171 Mitel UCC[1043:f03] Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: _transitionedWindowBeforeContents != nil

The "Enter Full Screen" menu option is also disabled now.

This worked at some point from both the menu option and image in upper right hand corner of window, and suddenly just quit working (we are still coding). Note I do receive the `customWindowsToEnterFullScreenForWindow` delegate notification (it returns nil) but do not see the `windowDidFailToEnterFullScreen` notify.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.